Are function arguments laid out in memory the same way as structs?
The question arises from the following idea.
There is a function, that acts as a proxy/hook of a true function, e.g.
int foo(int a, float b, void* c, std::string d, int& e, int f) {
    // possible bookkeeping here
    // ...

    // notice missing "a" argument, passing a *tail* of all arguments
    return foo_impl(b, c, d, e, f);
}

Can't change foo's interface, can change the foo_impl.
Now, I would like to call foo_impl with minimal overhead, in particular with saving on argument copying, e.g.
struct FooArgs {
   float b; 
   void* c; 
   std::string d;
   int& e;
   int f;
};

int foo_impl(FooArgs* args);

int foo(int a, float b, void* c, std::string d, int& e, int f) {
    // ...
    auto args = FooArgs{b, c, d, e, f};
    return foo_impl(&args);
}

No luck, still need to pack all arguments into FooArgs.
It should be possible to acquire a pointer to foo::b argument, and reinterpret it as FooArgs*
int foo(int a, float b, void* c, std::string d, int& e, int f) {
    // ...
    return foo_impl(reinterpret_cast<FooArgs*>(&b));
}

I haven't tried it in action, but I smell undefined behavior. Is it the case?

That is implementation detail

an intermediate copy will not get you less copies, but why are members of FooArgs  not references?

reinterpret_cast<FooArgs*>(&b) is 100% UB.  Some OSes store left to right and some OSes store right to left.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai yup, I missed that, but they should be indeed references where makes sense

i mean make all of them (const) references. Then there are no copies

Regarding the question in the title: the standard gives no guarantee about the layout of function paramaters in memory.

Thanks all for the answers!

I think what you are actually looking for is std::tie

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention, the arguments might not be him main memory at all, they could be in registers

Not only this is UB, it is pretty much always wrong. Just don't.

Main question here is: what for? (Unless just for educational purposes)

A struct or class can have padding between members.  There is no padding when passing parameters to functions.

@alagner it's a hooking layer for a graphical API (Vulkan), a lot of functions shall be hooked the way I've shown in the question. There are a lot of hot functions, where overhead is undesired. Moreover the underlying functions (aka foo_impl are callbacks provided by some other side code, so the only thing I can play around with is the signature of foo_impl and how it receives its data

Have you considered std::tie, std::forward_as_tuple or maybe creating a custom function of their kind that would either copy or move the arguments? I might be wrong (the profiler will tell the actual truth), but your case looks like "policy-based forwarding" to me :)

@AlexeyS.Larionov whatever you are trying to do, it is a micro optimization that likely won't have any observable effect.

In most cases with functions with reasonable numbers of arguments, all of the arguments will be passed in registers on modern general purpose system calling conventions, and none will directly be passed by memory. For Microsoft AMD64 the first 4 non-floating point, and first 4 floating point arguments will be passed by register. For SystemV AMD64 the first 6 non-floating point and first 8 floating point arguments will be passed by register. For ARM64 the first 8 non-floating point and first 8 floating point arguments are passed by register.
On x86-64, struct and class arguments 'passed by register' are stored on the stack, but the exact arrangement is up to the compilers convenience at that specific call site, with a pointer to the location passed by register allowing the value to be passed down efficiently so long as there is no need to create a copy.
On ARM, struct and class arguments are flattened to a list of fields, before constructing the list of arguments, with the first 8 non-FP and FP items from those lists of fields being passed by register, so a class with a lot of fields could quickly use all the register arguments.
As such, if you are taking one argument off the start of the function arguments, and absolutely need to optimize to avoid the register overhead, the minimum option is a combination of two things: Have foo_impl take all class parameters by rvalue reference so the copy constructor does not need to be invoked. And two, pass the unneeded parameter anyway. It is cheaper to pass the parameter and let foo_impl discard it, than it is to not pass it, and require foo to rearrange the arguments to fit.
However this is an extreme micro optimisation and only saves you up to 8 movs in the worst case. So I would only do it after profiling has identified this as a significant hotspot. I would also recommend reading the generated assembly if you are in this situation to check that the calling convention is interacting in the way you expect.
Your idea of trying to get access to a pointer to b is undefined behavior, would not work, and even if the compiler made it work, would likely result in an even slower call than the original mechanism as the register arguments would need to be spilled to the stack and then read back in again in foo_impl. This would involve a bunch of L1 accesses which are more expensive than the register-register moves needed by the naive approach.

Actually I never knew that simple arguments are passed via registers. I always assumed they're just pushed onto stack and grabbed on the called site (i.e. equivalent to making a struct with arguments right before calling the function). Good to know that direct passing is not much of an issue then

This is incorrect. ABIs are not decided by the ISA, it's entirely up to the compilers. The ABI used by gcc and clang on x64 is Itanium, and Itanium passes trivial class objects as their individual members in registers.

@PasserBy the summary on isa is an oversimplification. It is part of the ABI. However there is exactly one ABI set by ARM on ARM64, and both ABIs on AMD64 do it the same way

On x64, msvc passes class objects larger than 8 bytes on the stack even if it's trivial, in contrast to Itanium. Godbolt example.

That ABI annoyed people quite a bit actually.

They are, with some caveats. First, the argument order may well be reversed in memory., and thus the struct will need to be as well. Second floating-point often have special handling. Third, many calling conventions pass some number of arguments in registers (this is particularly true of floating-point arguments), the convention may or may not preserve spill space (the one I'm familiar with - x64 - does, I don't know if others do not).
I know that old windows code actually took advantage of this at times, take a look at the arguments to CreateWindowEx(A|W) and the definition of the CREATESTRUCT(A|W) structs and you will see that they are reversed (the CreateWindowEx(A|W) being the variant with an order that makes sense to the programmer, so it can be assumed to be primary).

On x64 first float argument will pretty much always be passed in xmm register. I don't know whether it is guaranteed that taking address forces all params to be pushed to stack and in correct order. Regardless, the result would be the same as OPs FooArgs* solution, except UB and completely unsafe and not portable.

The registers is a lot more significant in this case. Unless you have a lot of arguments, all the arguments will be passed in registers. The example function foo only passes one argument on the stack on Microsoft AMD64, and none on SystemV AMD64.

@freakish Taking an address forces the variable in the function to exist in the stack. However, the parameter in the function call is a nominally different binding of the value, and thus taking the address has no impact on whether the parameter value is passed by register or memory.

@user1937198 -- no it doesn't force the compiler to put it on stack, it's an undefined behavior and that lets compiler to ignore anything.

@Gene I assumed that freakish was referring to the normal idea of taking the address of b. Taking the address of b is not undefined behavior. Its only when you take that pointer and try to cast it to a FooArgs* and then dereference that pointer that UB is invoked.

@user1937198 yes, I was refering to OP's last snippet. My point is that if parameter is in register but I want to take its address, then it has to be copied to stack anyway (unless optimized away, lets ignore that). And so at that point using auto args = FooArgs{b, c, d, e, f}; has the same performance, but is simply safe and portable.
